# open balloon automatically at certain zoom level kml

Tags: kml, google-earth

i have a kml with polygons, and what i want to do is to automatically open correspondent label at certain zoom level, is it possible?
Where to look?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Look into using Network Links
http://code.google.com/apis/kml/documentation/kmlreference.html#networklink

and loading them via the onRegion viewRefreshMode
http://code.google.com/apis/kml/documentation/kmlreference.html#viewrefreshmode